# element whose childen are all of the same type

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to figure out an xPath that would return all elements in a document that contain only children of the same type (tag name).

For example:

```
<doc>
  <el id="1">
    <xxx>...</xxx>
    <xxx>...</xxx>
    <xxx>...</xxx>
  </el>
  <abc id="2">
    <yyy>...</yyy>
    <yyy>...</yyy>
    <yyy>...</yyy>
    <yyy>...</yyy>
  </abc>
  <el id="3">
    <zzz>...</zzz>
  </el>
  <el id="4">
    <xxx>...</xxx>
    <yyy>...</yyy>
    <zzz>...</zzz>
    <def id="5">
      <zzz>...</zzz>
      <zzz>...</zzz>
      <zzz>...</zzz>
    </def>
  </el>
</doc>
```

Would return elements with id 1, 2 and 5, but not 3 because it has only one child, and not 4 because it has several children but they're not the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//*[*[2]][not(*[name() != name(../*[1])])]
```

Breaking it down, first we find all the elements anywhere in the tree that have at least two children, and then for each of those elements the following:

```
*[name() != name(../*[1])]
```

selects the list of all that element's children whose name is different from that of the *first* child of the element in question.  The elements you're ultimately interested in are those for which this expression selects nothing, i.e. the elements for which *all* the children have the same name as the first one.

You could use

```
//*[@id][*[2]][not(*[name() != name(../*[1])])]
```

if you want to limit the search to just those elements that have an `id` attribute.

Comment: What if I have not only `el` elements and if they're not always at the same depth? (I've updated the example)

Comment: @Samy just use an initial `//*` instead of the `/doc/el` to check elements at all levels.

Comment: what does `[*[2]]` mean?

Comment: @Samy that's how I filter to include only elements that have at least two children - `*[*[2]]` says "select all elements that have a second child element regardless of name".  Without this check, all elements that have no children or one child would trivially satisfy the main predicate.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0. In XPath 2.0 it would be

```
//*[count(*) gt 1 and count(distinct-values(*/node-name())) eq 1]
```